# Hiding "*_files"

Tags: 14.04, ls

When I download web pages complete, I get the html file plus a folder with an `_files` name.

So every time I `ls` I get a list of all those files.

Renaming is a drag.

How can I get those out of my sight so I can see the real sub directories in my `ls`?

Answer (score 2):

You could define [**alias**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alias.1posix.html) in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
 alias ls="ls --hide='*_files'"
```

save your change and run:

```
 source .bashrc
```

After this command, if you want to view full content of folder you can use:

```
 ls -a
```

Comment: Won't this just anything explictly named "*_files".

Comment: @amanthethy: I apologize, but I did not understand your comment, could you explain better, I'm sorry but English is not my language

Comment: Won't this just hide* anything named "*_files".

Comment: I tested on lubuntu 12.04 and it hides file that match "*_files" pattern. `ls` doesn't show those file like `.` and `..`. This doesn't prevent `page.html` to works if you open it in browser. Sorry, I really don't know if this is relevant with your comment :)

Comment: I was confused as to whether the --hide option would pick up the * as a wildcard or as as part of the filename.

Comment: "*_files" means every file whose name ends with `_files`, so it hides google_files, apple_files, and so on. If you try to save web page in folder, you'll see one file `titlePage.html` and `titlePage_files` folder and if you try `ls --hide='*_files'` you'll see only `titlePage.html`

Comment: Oh no, I understand that. Its more the difference between *_files and "*_files" that I'm concerened with here. I assumed the --hide option would take the enquoted text ('*_files') as a string literal instead of seeing the asterik as a wildcard operator.

Comment: ah! okey, now I understand your doubt!

Answer (score 1):

`cd _files && ls`

or

`find . -type f`

The `_files` directory is a real sub-directory. Images, JavaScript, CSS, etc… are saved in that directory, and the original HTML file re-written to load them from there, when you save a web page to disk, inside Firefox or Chrom{e,ium}.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide them. They contain your webpage contents. The HTML files are the pages themselves.

To list only the subdirectories - without the files - present in the current folder you can use: `ls -d */` or `echo */` or `ls -l | grep "^d"`